# creating interface object and assigning that object static method?

Tags: java, object, interface

```
connection con = DriverManager getconnection(URL,user,pwd);
```

How is this possible ?
Here connection is interface,

How can we create object of interface ?

and then after we are assigning connection's object DriverManager class's static method getconnection.
how does this everything works ?
bit confuse

if the above code is possible then following should work but it shows me error

```
interface h
{
public int r=7;
public void set(int u);
}

class A implements h
{
public static int t=6;
int y=6;

public static void get()
{
    System.out.println(t*8);
}

public void set(int u)
{
    System.out.println(y*u);    
}   
}

class S_tatic
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{

    h l= new h();                      // it shows me error

    h l = A.get();                    //if this can be done then what's                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

                                     //meaning of static ?
}
}
```

now why can't i create here interface's object ?

and say once we create the interface object then how can we assign object to any method

i think we should go in following manner,

l.set();  // in case of non-static method

A.get(); // in case of static method

if this is true then how first jdbc syntax which i include here works ?

Comment: Interface can not be instantianted, it can only serve as reference for the objects of classes which implement that interface.

Comment: Maybe you should start with [What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).  Interfaces are the cornerstone of polymorphism and you should take the time to learn more about them

Comment: An interface is a contract which states what any given implement can do or will provide, it means that you should never care about "how" the interface is physically implemented, on that it "does" abide to the specified interface contract

Answer (score 0):

There is just one main rule about interfaces: *you can't initialize them with* `new InterfaceName()`.

Now, does this code violate that rule? (I changed it to make it better-looking)

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getconnection(URL,user,pwd);
```

Can you even find the word `new` there? No! This means that it does not violate the rule, so it compiles.

Let's look at your code:

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{

    h l= new h();

    h l = A.get();
}
```

Look at the first line of `main`, `new h()`! You violated the rule! Hence, it does not compile. (The second line also can't compile because `get` returns `void` btw)

In fact, in the `DriverManager.getConnection` method, it might contain some code like this:

```
Connection con = new XXXConnection();
```

where `XXXConnection` is a class that implements `Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

Interface, as the word denotes whether in context of language or real world is a way to achieve abstraction.

I would suggest you just once go through the Interface concepts in Java reference:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

From reference :
In its most common form, an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies. A bicycle's behavior, if specified as an interface, might appear as follows:

```
interface Bicycle {

    //  wheel revolutions per minute
    void changeCadence(int newValue);

    void changeGear(int newValue);

    void speedUp(int increment);

    void applyBrakes(int decrement);
}
```

In simple words if you say we specify what a Bicycle does through a interface. But implementation classes for e.g. RangerBicycle or MountainBicycle would define the real time entities or objects for behavior defined in interface.

So while your are trying to 'instantiate an interface' the compiler shows you error message that it cannot instantiate the given type as it is an interface.

Yes, you can create interface reference variables which can point to the objects of the implementing classes.